# Loading image showcase in array from url with forward, back buttons in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode, url, swift3

The code below works perfectly to display images from an already pre-existing array "var files". I want to load a list of image urls from another url to put in that array.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var fwdBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var bkBtn: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!

    var files = ["https://www.testsite.com/1.jpg", "https://www.testsite.com/2.jpg”,”https://www.testsite.com/3.jpg"]

    var count = 0

    //Foward Button
    @IBAction func fwdBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if (count < (files.count - 1)) {
            count = count + 1
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: files[count])
        }
    }

    //Back Button
    @IBAction func bkBtn(_ sender: Any) {
        if (count > 0) {
            count = count - 1
            imageView.image = UIImage(named: files[count])
        }
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: files[count])
}
```

I have tried to do the following to load images from URL but it either gives me a '**nil**' error, or a '**Cannot use instance member within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available**'

```
var files = [myurl()]

func myurl() {
    let myURLString = "https://www.testsite.com/image_list.php"
    guard let myURL = URL(string: myURLString) else {
        print("Error: \(myURLString) doesn't seem to be a valid URL")
        return
    }

    do {
        let myHTMLString = try String(contentsOf: myURL)

        let imagesOutput = myHTMLString


    } catch let error {
        print("Error: \(error)")
    }
}
```

The output image url list on image_list.php is just a plain text, comma separated url list without any html formatting like this:

```
https://www.testsite.com/1.jpg,https://www.testsite.com/2.jpg,https://www.testsite.com/3.jpg
```

I want to add the list of image urls from another url into an array in the declarations part of the ViewController. How do I properly integrate this into my code? I guess it doesn't have to be exactly that as long as it works. Thanks!

Comment: Are you trying to display photos that `image_list.php` returns?

Comment: Yes. image_list.php returns just    https://www.testsite.com/1.jpg,https://www.testsite.com/2.jpg,https://www.testsite.com/3.jpg" in plain text, no formatting, etc. If some sort of formatting is needed to work with the code it can be added in. I can make image_list.php do whatever.